# Cannot override application settings in IIS for ASP.NET Core 3.1 Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core

I typically do not put our sensitive information in our `appsettings.json` files and instead prefer to directly override the application settings via the `Configuration Editor` in IIS. I've been doing this for years with quite a lot of success, but I've recently borked something up in our application templates, and they no longer appear to see the settings from IIS at all.

Here is the general template for our applications' `Program.cs`.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static readonly string? Namespace = typeof(Program).Namespace;
    public static readonly string? AppName = Namespace?.Substring(Namespace.LastIndexOf('.', Namespace.LastIndexOf('.') - 1) + 1);
    public static readonly string? Environment = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
    public static readonly string? MachineName = System.Environment.MachineName;

    private static IConfiguration _configuration = null!;
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        _configuration = GetConfiguration();

        Log.Logger = CreateSerilogLogger(_configuration);

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Configuring web host ({ApplicationContext})...", AppName);
            var host = BuildWebHost(args);

            Log.Information("Starting web host ({ApplicationContext})...", AppName);
            host.Run();

            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Program terminated unexpectedly ({ApplicationContext})!", AppName);
            return 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    private static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .CaptureStartupErrors(false)
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseConfiguration(_configuration ?? GetConfiguration())
            .UseSerilog()
            .Build();

    private static ILogger CreateSerilogLogger(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var seqServerUrl = configuration["Serilog:SeqServerUrl"];
        var logstashUrl = configuration["Serilog:LogstashgUrl"];
        return new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationContext", AppName)
            .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", Environment)
            .Enrich.WithProperty("MachineName", MachineName)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.Seq(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(seqServerUrl) ? "http://seq" : seqServerUrl)
            .WriteTo.Http(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(logstashUrl) ? "http://localhost:8080" : logstashUrl)
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
    }

    private static IConfiguration GetConfiguration()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why my settings from `web.config` and IIS's configuration editor are not working?

Comment: Why are you expecting it to read settings from web.config? ASP.NET Core is not the same as the old ASP.NET.

Comment: I could've sworn we had been configuring it through there since ASP.NET Core 1.x, but I may just be mistaken. It appears IIS does also have an Environment Variable section, and I can attempt to use that instead.

Comment: If you've actually got sensitive info, you should be storing it in something like [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) or [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/).